# Show that $M^{-1}(O)=\{(r,x) \in \mathbb{R} \times V \mid rx \in O\}$ is open if $O$ is open and $(V,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

I have been spending a bit too much time on this problem so any help is appreciated. $(V,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological vector space and $O\in \mathcal{T}$ is an open set in $V$. Define $M^{-1}(O)=\{(r,x) \in \mathbb{R} \times V \mid rx \in O\}$. Show that $M^{-1}(O)$ is open in $\mathbb{R} \times V$ (in the standard product topology). As I understand it, for any given $(r,x) \in M^{-1}(O)$, I need to find an open set $W$ in $\mathbb{R} \times V$ such that $(r,x) \in W$ and $W \subset M^{-1}(O)$ but I am unable to come up with such a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(V,\tau)$ is a topological vector space (over $\Bbb R$) iff $V$ is a vector space (with $+,-,\cdot$ as operations, say), $\tau$ is a topology (often assumed to be at least Hausdorff) and such that

1. $p: V \times V \to V$ defined by $p(x,y)=x+y$, is continuous where all products have the product topogy (here and later).
2. $m: V \to V$ defined by $m(x)=-x$, is continuous.
3. $M: \Bbb R \times V \to V$ defined by $M(r,x)=r\cdot v$, is continuous.

Then your $M^{-1}[O]$ is just open because of the third axiom. So nothing to prove.

Comment: Axiom 2 follows from 3, so no need to include that.

Comment: @ε--δ true, if you know that $-v = -1 \cdot v$, which requires an extra argument. Just to emphasize that $(V,+)$ is a topological group, so one can use a lot of those results in TVS's as well.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the terrible question, not sure how I could miss this. I was so focused on constructing $W$ that I missed that $M$ is continuous by def. Oh well..

Comment: @Emma you live and learn... happy studies!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating this.

In a topological vector space $V$, by definition the scalar multiplication map

$$f: \mathbb{R} \times V \to V: (r, v) \mapsto rv$$

is continuous.

Thus if $O$ is open in $V$, then the inverse image $f^{-1}(O) = \{(r,v) \in \mathbb{R} \times V: rv \in O\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R} \times V$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks! Both answers are equally helpful so I simply picked the first one.

Comment: Actually, my answer was posted 2 minuts earlier than the other one, but it doesn't matter! Most important thing is that you were helped! Have a good day :)

Comment: That is true. Sorry about that. Henno's answer appeared first on the page for some reason... Thanks again.